# Why can't see my pictures on android? (Python/Kivy App)

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm using kivy on App. I'm able to take pictures and save them, but not to view on Android. Well, at least on normal way... 
I save the pictures on '/storage/emulated/0/'. I put a os.path.isfile to make sure the files exists and yes, I got True! Using "File Manager App" on my cell phone I can see the pictures, but they don't appear when I plug my usb cable to see them using my notebook and neither when I use "Gallery" on my cell phone. This is the code for the camera:

`def chamar_camera(nome,pc,media,objeto,label_passa,instance): 

    agora = datetime.now()
    nome_arquivo = '/storage/emulated/0/%s_%s_%.4i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i.jpg' % (nome,pc,agora.year,agora.month,agora.day,agora.hour,agora.minute,agora.second)
    def sair(label_passa,instance):         
        if os.path.isfile(nome_arquivo):texto = u'Foto de '+pc+u' armazenada com sucesso\n'
        else: texto = u'Foto de '+pc+u' nao pode ser armazenada\n'  
        texto = texto + os.getcwdu()        
        label_passa.text = texto
    camera.take_picture(nome_arquivo, on_complete=partial(sair,label_passa))`

Anybody had the same problem?

Comment: Well, now I can see the pictures but there is a delay... I can see pictures I took yesterday and some hours ago... very strange... On File Manager I can see all of them.

Comment: I think this is due to Android's media indexing running only occasionally, and that the right way to fix it is to tell it to run immediately. I'm not sure about the details though. Feel free to open a bug about it on github if there isn't one already.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll still keep this question open.